# JavaScript Roman Numeral Converter

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand this solution properly. I understood the Array declaration part but I am not sure what's going on in the while loop.

```
function roman(num) {
  var decimalValue = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
  var romanNumeral = ['M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD', 'C', 'XC', 'L', 'XL', 'X', 'IX', 'V', 'IV', 'I'];
  var romanized = '';

  for (var index = 0; index < decimalValue.length; index++) {
    while (decimalValue[index] <= num) {
      romanized += romanNumeral[index];
      num -= decimalValue[index];
    }
  }

  return romanized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time you're stuck on a loop-based problem like this, I would suggest learning about the [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) command and [breakpoints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint).

---

Let's use a specific number as an example, say... 2,652. Here's what will happen:

- Starting with 1,000 (the first number in `decimalValue`), check if 2,562 > 1,000.
- It is! So, we know that the Roman numeral for 2,652 has at least one M in it. We add M to our output Roman numeral.
- We've "accounted for" 1,000 of our number as a numeral, so we remove 1,000 from the number. We now have 1,562.
- We jump back up to checking if `num` > 1,000. It still is. So, we add another M and subtract another 1,000. Now we have 562 of our number "unaccounted for."
- This time, when we jump up to the start of our `while()` loop to test if `num` > 1,000, we find that it isn't the case! So the loop does not run this time.

This process repeats for all the numbers in `decimalValue`; all the numbers that have Roman numeral equivalents.

So, we check 900/CM, and find that this number (which is now down to 562) can not be represented as a sum including 900.

Next, we check 500, and find that it can! We add the Roman numeral for 500 to our current `romanized` string and carry on. We now have `MMD` and our number is down to 62 "unaccounted for" digits/units/whatever we're counting.

The next number to catch our `while()` loop is 50, since 62 > 50. We add the L for 50 and bring our number down to 12. Then again on 10, and we add an X. Finally, we match on the last item in `decimalValue`, 1, twice, and add two `I`s.

Our final string for this number, 2,652, is [`MMDXII`](http://romannumerals.babuo.com/MMDLXII-roman-numerals).

Answer (score 0):

The While loop does a comparison starting from index zero to the last and compares if the value of num passed in is less that the value at index of decimal value array if it is, It will then it appends(concatenate) the ruman numeral at that particular index to the randomize and subtract the equivalent number in decimal(mutate the num variable) from the num which was sent in.
It then checks if num is still greater than the value at that particular index indicating decimal.
taking a walk through with 3002 as example.

1. First check if index 0 which has 1000 is less than 3002 true
2. Set randomize to ruman numeral at position index. In this case we have 'M' then subtract decimal at position index from num(3002) we now have num = 2002.
3. The while loop iterate again and check is 1000 less than 2002? yes it is so it will execute the body of the while loop again.
4. Append(Concatenate the value at position index(which has not changed yet) to the randomize variable this case index is still zero so we appending 'M' now randomize is 'MM'. Subtract the decimal at position index(0) from num(2002) we now have num = 1002.
5. Iterate the while loop and check if decimal value at position index(0) of the decimalValue array is less than num(1002) which is true in this case. execute the loop as before.
   Append(Concatenate the value at position index(which has not changed yet) to the randomize variable this case index is still zero so we appending 'M' now randomize is 'MMM'. Subtract the decimal at position index(0) from num(1002) we now have num = 2.
6. Iterate the while loop and check if decimal value at position index(0) of the decimalValue array is less than num(2) which is `false` in this case. Stop execution of the loop and increment the value of index in the for loop and do the checks again. till you reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

decimalValue[i] represents the same value as `romanNumeral[i]` for any `i`. This represents the same data as if the author used a object `{4:"IV", 5:"V", ...}` except objects to not preserve order. Since the author wants to check larger numbers before smaller numbers, they use this to preserve order and also associate the decimal values with the Roman Numerals.

The loop is confusing because javascript uses `+` to represent both numerical addition, `2+4==6`, and string concatenation, `"a"+"b"=="ab"`.

`romanized += romanNumeral[index]` means append the string contained in `romanNumberal[index]` to the end of the string `romanized`.

`num -= decimalValue[index];` means decrease `num` by the number contained in `decimalValue[index]`

```
  //start at the big values that have roman number codes, then try smaller values
  for (var index = 0; index < decimalValue.length; index++) {
    //if the value we are testing is less or equal to num 
    // (actually loop but for reasons explained below)
    while (decimalValue[index] <= num) {

      //append the string in romanNumberal to 
      //the end of the string in the variable romanized
      romanized += romanNumeral[index];

      //from the number num, substract the
      //value we just added to romanized 
      num -= decimalValue[index];

      //what about a case like 3, which needs 
      //repeated letters in that case "III".

      //That is why this is a while statement and not an if. 
      //the while loop keeps processing 
      //those cases until we have enough repeated letters.
    }
  }
```

When we need more than one of the same the same letter, then `decimalvalue[index]` will still be less than or equal to `num`.

This is because when we reach `decimalvalue[index]`, we know that `num  < decimalvalue[index-1]` (except for the start), because the while loop prevents `index` from increasing until that is true.

Often the loop only runs once. For example, going from `decimalvalue[index] == 10` to `decimalvalue[index] == 9` loop only runs once at most because `num < 10` and `10-9==1` which is less than 9. So then, the while loop acts as just an if statement.

The loop only loops for values where duplicate letters are valid in roman numerals, because that is were the drop in value between `decimalvalue[i-1]` and `decimal[i]` is great enough. More precisely those are the only times when `decimalvalue[i-1]/decimalvalue[i] >= 2` (that is 2 or more of a value in `decimalvalue[i]` fits in the previous decimalvalue)

if you know the division algorithm from math this is kinda like that.

Answer (score 0):

Found this codepen on google.  The code is pretty straightforward, I hope it will help.

[Roman Numeral Converter in Javascript](https://codepen.io/HarryBerry99/pen/qBKLwmd)

```
function convert(num){
    num = parseInt(num);
    
    var result = '',
        ref = ['M','CM','D','CD','C','XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I'],
        xis = [1000,900,500,400,100,90,50,40,10,9,5,4,1];
    
    if (num >= 4000) {
        num += ''; // need to convert to string for .substring()
        result = '<span style="border-top: 1px solid; margin-top: 2px; display: inline-block; padding-top: 0px;">'+convert(num.substring(0,num.length-3))+'</span>';
        num = num.substring(num.length-3);
    }
    
    for (x = 0; x < ref.length; x++){
        while(num >= xis[x]){
            result += ref[x];
            num -= xis[x];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


$('input').on('keyup keydown change',function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();
    if (val.length == 0) return $('#result').html('');
    if (isNaN(val)) return $('#result').html('Invalid input');
    if (e.type == 'keydown'){
        if (e.keyCode === 38) $this.val(++val);
        if (e.keyCode === 40) $this.val(--val);
    }
    if (val < 1) return $('#result').html('Number is too small');
    
    $('#result').html(convert(val));
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33351380)